# get the index of an element from the original list and the value of the remaining element

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, josephus

I'm trying to solve a [Josephus problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem) where, in addition to the value of the remaining element, I need to return its index in the original list. I implemented the list myself and it works well, I get the value correctly, but I can’t figure out how to get the index from the original array!
Can anyone explain this to me please?

My code:

```cpp
#include "circular_linked_list.h"

enum class direction { clockwise, counterclockwise };

template<typename T>
std::pair<int, T> Josephus_problem(CircularLinkedList<T> list, direction dir, unsigned step) {
    if (list.getLength() == 0) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("List is empty");
    }

    int currentIndex = 0;
    int size = list.getLength();
    int finalIndex = 0;
    while (list.getLength() > 1) {
        if (dir == direction::counterclockwise) {
            finalIndex -= step + 1;//???
            currentIndex = (currentIndex - step + 1) % list.getLength();
        } else {
            finalIndex += step - 1;//???
            currentIndex = (currentIndex + step - 1) % list.getLength();
        }

        list.removeAt(currentIndex);
    }

    finalIndex = ...;//Don't know what to do here!
    return {finalIndex, list[0]};
}
```

Comment: Build a list of indexes - just integers 0 through `list.getLength()-1`. Play the game on that. At the end you would have the surviving index. Look up the surviving value in the original list, using this index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much this:

Initialize a std::list of unsigned integers (size_t) that represent the index of each element in the list from 0 to N-1.

```
std::list<size_t> listOfPositions;
size_t N = <how ever many elements are in your original list>
for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    listOfPositions.push_back(i);
}
```

Then just iterate through the list one by one.  Each time you hit the STEPth element, you erase it. You can take advantage of the fact that `list.erase` on a position element will return the next item after.

Here's the simple logic:

```
unsigned int index = 1;
auto pos = listOfPositions.begin();

while (listOfPositions.size() > 1) {
    if (index == step) {
        pos = listOfPositions.erase(pos); // returns the next item in the list
        index = 1;
    }
    else {
        pos++;
        index++;
    }

    if (pos == listOfPositions.begin()) {
        pos = listOfPositions.end();
    }
}
```

And you can take advantage of reverse iterators for the counterclockwise operations.  Some small tweaks to the above logic to make it work for reverse iterations.

```
unsigned int index = 1;
auto pos = listOfPositions.rbegin() + N - 1; // point to the first item in the list
while (listOfPositions.size() > 1) {
    if (index == step) {
        pos = listOfPositions.erase(pos); // return the previous item in the list when using reverse iterators
        index = 1;
    }
    else {
        pos++;
        index++;
    }

    if (pos == listOfPositions.rend()) {
        pos = listOfPositions.rbegin();
    }
}
```

In both cases, the "last remaining index" is this:

```
size_t last_remaining = *pos;
```

Comment: Another thing I thought of. Instead of having alternate implementations of the loops for clockwise vs counter-clockwise, just initialize the list items in reverse with 0 still being the first item. Instead of `0,1,2,3,4,5,6` initialize it as `0,6,5,4,3,2,1` for counterclockwise. Then you won't need the rbegin/rend version of the iteration loop to solve.